# Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth autoconnect not working

Tags: linux, bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04

I have headphones Xiaomi AirDots. When I am turning on headphones they are connecting to my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) but immediately disconnecting.

After that when I trying to connect manually, it not connects some time (about 10 sec). But if I am trying to connect manually immediately when I turned on headphones, it connects without problems.

I tried to remove the package "blueman", tried to remove and pair again, not helped.